# Dynamically changes the position of ImageView

Tags: android, position, imageview, android-linearlayout, touch-event

I have 3 ImageViews in LinearLayout(Horizontal Orientation). I want to show them according to move touches to the left or right. First of all, I have to create 3 imageviews inside of the LinearLayout and only the one of the 3 imageviews can be visible. In TouchEvent I want to change position of the visible one,then I want to show smoothly the other one like books in iBooks. How can I do that?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below example. This will be helpful to  you.
[here](http://www.anddev.org/a_androidwidgetgallery_-_example-t332.html)

Comment: No, Gallery is not suitable choice for my app. Since, my app will look like iBooks app. You touch from right to left to change the picture in a full screen mode.

Comment: You need to modify this example. This is for your reference.